# How to add a dynamic value to a notification using flutter_local_notifications?

Tags: flutter, notifications, alerts

How to add a dynamic value, like a countdown, to a notification using flutter_local_notifications?

For example, the body of this notification would count down from 60 to 0.

[image]

```
import 'package:flutter_local_notifications/flutter_local_notifications.dart';
import 'package:quiver/async.dart';

///etc.

  Future<void> addNotification() async {
    const androidDetail = AndroidNotificationDetails(
       ///etc.
        ongoing: true,);

    const iosDetail = IOSNotificationDetails();

    const notificationDetail = NotificationDetails(
      iOS: iosDetail,
      android: androidDetail,
    );

    int time = 0;

    CountdownTimer(const Duration(seconds: 60), const Duration(seconds: 1))
        .listen((event) {
      time = event.remaining.inSeconds;
      print('time is $time');
    });

    await _localNotificationsPlugin.show(
        id, 'timer', time.toString(), notificationDetail);
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, it's not possible to achieve real-time data update notifications directly.

However, there is a workaround! You can notify again using the **same notification ID**, which effectively replaces the previous notification with a new one. It's like indirectly updating the notification dynamically, which many developers usually do.

For instance, you can implement something like this:

```dart
import 'package:flutter_local_notifications/flutter_local_notifications.dart';
import 'package:quiver/async.dart';

Future<void> addNotification() async {
  const androidDetail = AndroidNotificationDetails(
    ///etc.
    ongoing: true,
  );

  const iosDetail = IOSNotificationDetails();

  const notificationDetail = NotificationDetails(
    iOS: iosDetail,
    android: androidDetail,
  );

  int time = 60; // countdown from 60 seconds

  await _localNotificationsPlugin.show(
    id,
    'timer',
    time.toString(),
    notificationDetail
  );

  CountdownTimer(const Duration(seconds: 60), const Duration(seconds: 1))
      .listen((event) {
    time = event.remaining.inSeconds;
    print('time is $time');

    _localNotificationsPlugin.show(
      id,
      'timer',
      time.toString(),
      notificationDetail
    );
  });
}
```

with async/await, if you want -

```dart
 CountdownTimer(const Duration(seconds: 60), const Duration(seconds: 1))
      .listen((event) async {
    time = event.remaining.inSeconds;
    print('time is $time');

    await _localNotificationsPlugin.show(
      id,
      'timer',
      time.toString(),
      notificationDetail
    );
  });
```

**I hope this helps you!**